# Google Maps - search within bounds / viewport

Tags: google-maps, maps, geocoding, viewport, bounds

I want my search to only return hits within the map/viewport.
I zoom in over Britain and search for London with the map bounds, but the
response also return 3 hits in the US. How do I limit the search?

Code:

```
function codeAddress(){
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var address = document.getElementById("inputAddress").value;
    var bounds = map.getBounds();
    geocoder.geocode({address: address, bounds: bounds}, function(results, status){
        if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            // put markers on each hit
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that by limiting the results you are trying to plot relevant markers right?

So instead of limiting the search directly, you can try the indirect approach. 
`if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK){
            // put markers on each hit
        }`

In the if loop you can use the method called **contains()** on the bounds of the map, like so

```
if(status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        if(map.getBounds().contains(RESULT-LOCATION)) {
            // put markers on each hit
        }
    }
```

Where the **RESULT-LOCATION** is the location of the result that is returned from the Geocode request. This way it will plot the markers only within the maps bounds.

Hope this helps.